# How can i get the RGB value of specific straight line in the image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

This is an image which there are two red(whatever color) lines. I want to detect the line and then want to get the rgb values of that line. How can I do this by using OpenV or any other library of python.

[image]

I tried this kind of code which print a list of many values:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Rizwan/Desktop/result.jpg')

print(img)
```

Comment: Could you give more details? You only need to know the RGB value of those lines or you want to locate them first?

Comment: Perhaps post your image to some free hosting service and put the URL here.

Comment: To get your specific line, you can use numpy slicing. To get the RGB value of that ROI you can use `cv2.split()`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. And for an image processing question, you usually have to supply a picture.

Comment: @aminrd first i want to locate those lines in images if lines exists in image then i want to get the rgb value of those lines.

Comment: Very hard to answer without seeing your image.

Comment: Hey @MarkSetchell, I added the image link in description.

Comment: Ok, will there always be 2 lines? Are the lines always vertical? Will the two lines have the same colour? What sort of answer do you expect as there are probably 700 shades of red in the sample image? Is the background colour always the same? Always constant? Sometimes chequered or patterned? If you want someone to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them.

Comment: No, there could be only one line or both two lines(left line will be always there but right line may or may not). and these always will be vertical and colour could be changed too little bit(most of the time it will be same). and i want to know the grb values of the line(what ever shades there are). background colour will be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to go to [HSV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and look for red tones. Reds are harder to find because they straddle 0 and 360 degrees on the Hue/Saturation/Value wheel so I will invert the image and look for cyan which is where red will show up in an inverted image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load the image as BGR
im = cv2.imread('strip.jpg')

# Invert image, i.e. 255-im, to make reds into cyan and convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(255-im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 

# Set low and high limit for the tones we want to identify - based on Hue of cyan=90 in OpenCV 
lo = np.uint8([80,30,0])
hi = np.uint8([95,255,255]) 

# Mask all red pixels
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv,lo,hi)

# Save mask for fun
cv2.imwrite('result1.png',mask)
```

That gives this:

[image]

Carrying on with the code, we now apply that mask to the original image to blacken uninteresting pixels:

```
# Zero out to black all uninteresting pixels in original image
im[mask<255] = 0
cv2.imwrite('result2.png',im)
```

[image]

```
# Reshape as a tall column of R, G, B values and find unique rows, i.e. unique colours
unique = np.unique(im.reshape(-1,3), axis=0)
print(unique)
```

That gives around 700 RGB triplets. Carrying on, grab the unique colours and write to an image so we can see them:

```
# This line is a hack based solely on the current image just for illustration
cv2.imwrite('unique.png',unique[:625,:].reshape((25,25,3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark Setchell, This helps me a lot. Please sure me how to get the RGB values of these detected lines?

Comment: The line that says `print(unique)` prints them. Try running the code.

Comment: By running the code i got these [[ 31  41  48] [ 33  43  50] [ 34  44  51]
...
 [241 243 243] [242 240 240] [242 244 244]] values. What are these values and how to understand these values? Please explain me i shall be thankful to you.

Comment: That means there is pixel with the colour `rgb(48,41,31)` and a pixel with the colour `rgb(50,43,33)` ... bear in mind that OpenCV stores in BGR format.

Comment: and what are these [241 243 243] [242 240 240] [242 244 244]] values? are these of second line?

Comment: They are all just RGB values that occur somewhere in the red lines - there is no relationship between which colour and where it occurs within the red lines.

Comment: Thanks Mark setchell, Its really helps me a lot. I will get back to you if need any more help.. thank you :)

Comment: Hey Mark how can i get the grb values separately of these two lines? For example right line's rgb values and left line's rgb values?

Comment: If you open the mask image in an image editor such as Photoshop or GIMP, you can see that left line has x-coordinates 280..320 and the right one has x-coordinates 430..460. As the image is 120 pixels tall, pixels half way between the top and bottom will have a y-coordinate of 60. So, for example `im[60,300]` will be in the middle of the left line and `im[60,445]` will be a pixel in the middle of the right line.

Comment: Is there any way by which i can crop these two lines in opencv and then process on these lines?

Comment: Sure... `left=im[:,280:320]` and `right=im[:,430:460]`

Comment: its giving error: IndexError: index 320 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3

Comment: Sorry, try `left=im[:,280:320,:]` and `right=im[:,430:460,:]`

Comment: But this is hard coded. what if i have an image where lines are not on these pixels? I want it to make automatic detection or cropping. Please help

Comment: Try calculating the mean of each column in the image, using `columnTotals = np.mean(mask, axis=0)` . You will see a whole load of zeroes, 1 for each column, until you come to the first column with some white in it - then the mean will increase as you pass the left line. When you get past it, the mean will drop again to zero. Then it will increase again when you meet the right line and drop again when you get to the right edge of the right line.

Comment: Can you please provide me some implementation of it? thanks!